# iOS - detect when application exits

Tags: ios, exit, quit

How can I detect when a user exits the application? (hitting the home button)
And how can I detect when the relaunch it? (clicking the icon)

*I'm not talking about users manually quitting the app by holding the home button and then making the icons wiggle and deleting the app instance from the sub-dock. i'm talking about just temporarily exiting the app buy clicking the home button.. maybe sending a text or whatnot then coming back to the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

In your AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! Now I can read more about those int he documentation as well! very helpful! Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a notification `UIApplicationDidGoToBackground` that fires when the home button is pressed. A similar notification tells you about going back to foreground.

Comment: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification is what worked for me