# Check for app shutdown/close

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to check when a user has shutdown/closed my app?

I want to save some data when this happens and I'm not sure if there's a way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - detect when application exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447690/ios-detect-when-application-exits)

Comment: I think you're right Black Frog, should I delete this post?

Comment: Don't delete.  Some searches will land on your question which will help people by pointing them in the right direction.

Comment: How on earth are those duplicates? This seems to ask how to detect if a user KILLS an app. That is just to detect if a user LEAVES an app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` method of the AppDelegate.

Save data, user settings in this method.

Answer (score 2):

When a user closes the app,  `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` gets called, which is located in the AppDelegate. You can do the needful in that.